# git ssh command on aws lamda git layer error

Tags: git, aws-lambda

I'm running simple-git on AWS Lambda with a GIT layer (https://github.com/lambci/git-lambda-layer) and everything works fine until I use `.env('GIT_SSH_COMMAND', 'ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ...')` with a custom SSH key - it throws `spawn git ENOENT`.

Works perfectly fine with the SSH key on the localhost, error happens only on lambda and only with the GIT_SSH_COMMAND env.

Any ideas why is this happening?

- Node 14 (Lambda)
- GIT 2.29.0 (via lambda layer)
- Lambda layer is installed properly, it works without GIT_SSH_COMMAND

Comment: Apparently there is no `ssh` command in the path. Which is odd since Git normally just *runs* ssh, but perhaps the AWS setup is ... different.

Answer (score 0):

Check where `ssh` is referenced in the `PATH` (`which ssh`), and use the full path of the `ssh` executable in your `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`

```
.env('GIT_SSH_COMMAND', 
     '/full/path/ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ...')
```